# MongoDB Connect to PRIMARY after failover (Azure)

Tags: mongodb, azure, centos

I've managed to get a MongoDB replica set going on Microsoft Azure VMs, with one PRIMARY, one SECONDARY, and one ARBITER VMs. all in the same virtual network... And I've managed to fail-over successfully.

However, now that I've failed over from my PRIMARY to SECONDARY (now SECONDARY / PRIMARY, respectively), I am unsure how to establish a connection to the primary from outside the network.  How do I default to the primary without having to specify the port number each time?  In other words, I want to simply connect my client to mysubnetname.cloudapp.net without having to change the port I'm connecting to from my local client.

Comment: Little surprised you are even using a replica set without properly reading http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/

Comment: Interesting.. So am I to list all the nodes in my cluster? Primary and Secondary nodes alike?  What if I have 1000+ nodes?  Also, I'm currently using the cmdline client.. not an application.. am I still suppose to use the same URI format?

Comment: In a nutshell yes. You really need to read some more and the whole 1000+ nodes concept might sink in. You should always specify more than one node to connect to, and the underlying driver ( also used by the shell ) will "discover" all the other nodes for you. But you choose more than one on the connection so there is somewhere else to go iniitially if the first node or others are down when connecting.